# Как сделать ЧПУ на сайте, написанном на Node.js?

Tags: node.js, seo, чпу

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на сайте, написанном на Node.js, реализуются чпу?

Comment: А ещё за ЧПУ в htaccess надо больно бить по рукам

Answer (score 1):

Через `req.url` определяете что поступает на вход, а далее уже прописываете логику в зависимости от структуры вашего сайта (запрашиваете данные из БД, шаблон страницы, подключаете нужные модули).

Как правило, в таких случаях также требуется отдельная таблица сопоставления path-части адреса с различными типами выводимых данных (информационная страница, профиль пользователя, лента публикаций и т.д.)